# Storing the pointer to a function pointer in a void*

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I understand why you cannot do:

```
void(*fp)(void) = &function;
function_taking_void_pointer((void*)fp);
```

because the lengths of the types may be different.

but is there anything wrong with adding annother layer of indirection:

```
void(*fp)(void) = &function;
void(**fpp)(void) = &fp;
function_taking_void_pointer((void*)fpp)
```

My thinking behind this: The pointer to the function pointer should be pointing to data memory and therefore should have the same length as the void* type.

So how wrong am I?

Comment: God help whoever has to read this code when you're done with it...

Comment: Of course void pointer are made for these kinds of 'hacks'. BUT I guess its definitly no good design to pass a function pointer to a function that maybe was made for the purpose of handling different datatypes like, int*,float*,double*, struct whatever* etc. So I think you better write a function that arguments are pointer to functions.

Comment: I should clarify, this is a question to improve my understanding of the language, I currently have no actual use case.

Comment: Ok, then forget about such weired stuff.

Comment: Hmmm... Well thats not very enlightening.

Comment: Ill already gave you a hint of why you should'nt do it. If you have no particular use case - stop thinking about solving a problem that is not really a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your previous insight, and I am in agreement with you that it would not be the best design choice.

Comment: Keep in mind that a function pointer may be stored in any other function pointer (via casting) as long as it it cast back to the correct function pointer type before being used to make a function call. So you can use a `void (*)(void)` (or whatever function pointer type) as a kind of "void*" for function pointers.

Comment: Also, POSIX sort of requires that a function pointer can be round-tripped through a `void*` because of how the `dlsym()` function is specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that all pointer types are *object types*:

N1570 6.3.5 Types, paragraph 20,  fifth list item:

> - **A pointer type may be derived from a function type** or an object type, called the
>     referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
>     to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T
>     is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
>     referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. **A pointer type is a complete
>     object type.**

But pointers to object types don't necessarily have same size as `void*` (6.2.5 p28).

> 28. **A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
>       pointer to a character type.**<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>       compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
>       pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
>       as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
>       alignment requirements as each other. **Pointers to other types need not have the same
>       representation or alignment requirements.**

However, they can all be **converted** to `void*` (6.3.2.3 p1):

> 1. A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>      any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>      compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about converting function pointer types to `void *`; you explicitly quote what it says: _A **pointer to void** may be converted to or from a **pointer to any object type**._ Functions are not objects; that's why it says _A pointer type may be derived from a function type **or** an object type_; the two sets of types (pointers to objects and pointers to functions) are not the same and are not necessarily convertible. POSIX even removed the text that used to provide a get-out clause. There are machines where function pointers are very elaborate (big, complex).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that is what my answer says. Keep in mind that question asked about *pointer to function pointer*. And that is object type and can be converted to `void*`.

Answer (score -5):

This code snippet is wrong.

```
    void(*fp)(void) = &function;
    function_taking_void_pointer((void*)fp);
```

In C/C++ the `function name` will be relocated to a specific address in `linking stage`, so you cannot use `&` before a `function name`. In addition `function name` is not a variable in C/C++, so you also cannot try to get its address.

Comment: If `foo()` is a function, you can use `&foo`. It's just the same as using `foo` itself.

Comment: Same as with statically allocated arrays. You can include the `&` and you can omit the `&`. The compiler will interpret it the same way.